# How to getDate and getMonth in Angular UI calendar?

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

When I use function:

```js
$scope.getDate = function() {
    return uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar1'].fullCalendar('getDate');
}
```

It returns wrong date after I switch to +2 or -2 months.
How can I get the date/month which I chose on calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Hello Can you try with this code on your calendar configuration for check date display okay or not?

```
viewRender:function( view, element ){
   console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

It will be correct display in my basic configuration even.
Hope it will be help.